# How to create tables, procedures, etc. on remote machine in sql server 2005/2008

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

I have prepared an installer which will deploy some files as well as will create database, tables, procedures, etc.

The problem is if the user wants to install db, procs. on remote server then I require SQL client to be installed on machine from where I am installing my application. I dont want to have this (as clients would not agree too)

I am taking input for database connection. Now I want to create all the tables, procedures, functions on remote server(provided by client) without having to install sql server client on local machine.

Thanks,
Sunil

Comment: The installer will require SQL client, or similar, on the on which machine you're installing. This is by design. How else are you expected to communicate with the server without the correct protocols?

Comment: The only option in that case would be to copy the files (scripts etc.) to the physical SQL Server machine and run them there (e.g. by remote-desktopping into it) - if you are allowed to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think by SQL CLient you mean the SQL Administration Tool. If I am correct, then you do not need to have this installed in order to create tables and run other DDL (Data Definition Language) statements like CREATE TABLE, etc.

You can just run the statements in your program (which probably has DML statements, such as SELECT, UPDATE, etc).  You do not need to have the administrative client installed to create the database tables and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your installer is capable of deploying all this metadata on a local server, correct?  It should be no different connecting to a remote database.  Just specify a different server when starting your connection.